# Business Add Phone Numbers permission issue with Facebook Graph API

Tags: curl, facebook-graph-api, permissions

With the [Facebook Marketing Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/business/add_phone_numbers/) I am attempting to add a new phone number to the WhatsApp business account.

My system user token is generated with business_management permission (When I debug the token, it appears to be OK).

Here's how I try to use this API:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.facebook.com/[MY_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID]/add_phone_numbers?phone_number=[NEW_PHONE_NUMBER]' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [MY_TOKEN]'
```

This is the error I get:

> "message": "(#136023) You do not have permission to access this endpoint"

Is there something I'm missing?